# Как определить корневой каталог сайта на хостинге hostland.ru?

Tags: хостинг

Сейчас занимаюсь доработкой сайта на хостинге hostland.ru. Столкнулся с проблемой - сайт создан с помощью конструктора, а файл-менеджер пока бесполезен, т к не могу определиться с корневым каталогом. Есть папка с таким именем, как домен, в ней папка htdocs, а в ней только одна папка new, внутри которой находятся все файлы сайта. Так вот, когда я создал в папке htdocs файл test.html и набрал ссылку на него в браузере в виде имя домена + test.html, то выдало 404. Т. е., получается, что это не корневой каталог. Тогда я создал такой же файл в папке new, но результат тот же. Может у кого-то есть сайт на этом хостинге, помогите разобраться. За раннее благодарен.

Comment: У них, насколько я знаю, стандартная схема папок. То есть вам для основного домена нужна папка /ваш_домен.ru/htdocs/www - в неё и кладите index.html или что у вас прописано в качестве основной индексной страницы

Comment: В том-то и дело, что нет папки www,  все файлы лежат в htdocs/new. Сайт не мой, дорабатываю на заказ. В каком файле находится главная страница index.html или index.php -не знаю и ничего такого не нахожу. Так же нет файла .htacces.

Comment: Создайте www, закиньте туда, иногда папка не создаётся

Comment: К сожалению, не помогло. Всё равно 404 :(

Comment: А логи доступны?

Comment: Наверно, нет, что-то не нашёл я в меню журнала ошибок.

Comment: Мне пришлось самому зарегаться на этом хостинге и получить активационное письмо, чтобы толком обо всём узнать. Да, действительно файлы сайта должны находиться в htdocs/www. Создал я там тестовый HTML-файл, в роде, как получилось, но через час он тоже стал выдавать 404... Кино и немцы.